# JSON в класс c#

Tags: c#, json

Коллеги, добрый день!
Помогите с JSON разобраться.

У меня есть пример JSON. Мне нужно перевести его в класс c#. Возникает проблема с наименованием полей.

Если его десериализовать в класс, то получается, не очень красивая ситуация, где имя класса - это ИДврача или ИДклиники.

Логичнее было бы завести три класса  Clinic, Doctor, Cells и их уже преобразовывать в данный json.

Есть ли какой-нибудь лаконичный способ это сделать? Что-нибудь вроде [JsonProperty(Doctor.ID)]. Или все таки придется вручную формировать его?

```
    {
  "ID клиники 1": "Название клиники 1",
  "ID клиники 2": "Название клиники 2",
  "data": {
    "ID клиники 1": {
      "ID врача 1": {
        "efio": "ФИО Врача 1",
        "espec": "Специальность врача",
        "cells":[
              { 
                 "dt": "2018-01-30", 
                 "time_start": "09:00", 
                 "time_end": "10:00", 
                 "free": true,
                 "room": "Кабинет 1"
              },
              { 
                  "dt": "2018-01-30", 
                  "time_start": "10:00", 
                  "time_end": "10:30", 
                  "free": false,
                  "room": "Кабинет 1"
              }
          ]
      }
    },

    "ID клиники 2": {
      "ID врача 1": {
        "efio": "ФИО Врача 1",
        "espec": "Специальность врача",
        "cells":[
              { 
                 "dt": "2018-01-29", 
                 "time_start": "12:00", 
                 "time_end": "13:00", 
                 "free": true,
                 "room": "Кабинет 1"
              },
              { 
                  "dt": "2018-01-29", 
                  "time_start": "10:00", 
                  "time_end": "10:30", 
                  "free": false,
                  "room": "Кабинет 1"
              }
          ]
      },
      "ID врача 3": {
        "efio": "ФИО Врача 3",
        "espec": "Специальность врача",
        "cells":[
              { 
                 "dt": "2018-01-15", 
                 "time_start": "17:00", 
                 "time_end": "18:00", 
                 "free": true,
                 "room": "Кабинет 2"
              }              
          ]
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете для десериализации?

Comment: newtonsoft json. Но вопрос закрыт. В принципе мне этого наверное достаточно будет)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov с другой стороны, для чего делают такие json? Мне нужно сериализовать класс в этот json. Теперь сидеть обертку придумывать. Я в принципе вопрос не правильно задал изначально)

Comment: Это вопрос на проектирование API. Где-то у вас есть данные в программе, вам их нужно выдать на выход в виде json'а. Можно хранить данные в виде, чтобы было как можно меньше трансформаций. Можно любой класс отправить в формат json, так зачем вам два разных класса? Попробуйте подумать, почему вы храните данные в ином виде и не стоит ли упростить.